# How to filter autocomplete

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am feeding Azure Search with data from multi-tenant database, so every document in the index has a property TenantId. For searching, aggregations, suggestions I always filter by "TenantId eq 'xxx'" depending on the user calling it.

However for autocomplete it is not possible to filter, so if it returns "something", the tenant in context might not have "something" in his data. Any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is actively being developed and will be completed before the Autocomplete API reaches General Availability. I'll update this thread once we deploy the change so you can try it.